# Google AutoML to Vertex Migration Fail - Text Classification not Working

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

My company runs a job board and one of the things we were using Google Cloud for is to classify each job posting (eg. marketing, hr, finance, sales, etc...).

Four years ago, in Natural Language AutoML, we created/imported a dataset, trained the model, and deployed - all worked smoothly and has done so for the duration.

Now we are told that product is deprecated and we need to migrate to VertexAI. That sucks but we have no option. Fortunately, there is a AutoML-Vertex Migration tool that Google provided so we followed all the steps and migrated the dataset and the model to VertexAI.

The problem is that we can't get it to work. When I navigate to the model on Vertex AI and click on the Deploy & Test tab and try to put some prediction sample data in, we get an error "Unable to test model [our model name here]" There link on the error to "View Issues" which shows.

```
The error details
The operation failed due to the following error(s): 
Internal error encountered.
```

It seems like our only option is to try to upload a new dataset to VertexAI, train a model on that dataset, and see if it works. The problem is this costs around $100 (at least it did on AutoML) and I'd rather not spend $100 for something that Google is forcing me to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20require%20more%20bandwidth%20than,byte%20and%20every%20millisecond%20count.)

Comment: @Rainysidewalks I thought I was pretty descriptive in my posting.  Would you prefer that I post it as-is...just without the image?

Comment: no problem sir ,better now